# Given $F(1)$ and $F'(x)$, compute $F(2)$.

Tags: derivatives

Given $F(1)=1$ and $\displaystyle F'(x)=\frac{4x^2}{1+5x^4}$, how to find $F(2)$?

Please give me some hints on how to find the value of $F$ at $x=2$..

Comment: What do you mean by an _interval_ for $F(2)$?

Comment: input x=2 into F(x)

Comment: I have edited your question based on your comment.  Check to see if this is what you mean

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Using Taylor expansion between $1$ and $2$,  we get

$$F (2)=F (1)+(2-1)F'(c) $$
with  $1 <c <2.$

thus
$$F (2)=1+F'(c) $$

and
$$F'(c)=\frac {8c (1-5c^4)   }{(1+5c^4)^2}$$

Comment: what is taylor expansion？

Comment: @杨柳青 It is a Generalization of MVT .

Comment: @杨柳青 FYI, Taylor expansion is [泰勒展开](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansion) and MVT (Mean Value Theorem) is [中值定理](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)

Comment: @FrenzyLi Thank you. How did you write this kind of link.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima `[Text to show](actual link)`. Click "help" under "Add Comment" for more information.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. Bye.